# ASA 5505 blocks users

Tags: firewall, cisco-asa

I have recently installed an ASA 5505. But now i have users that are being blocked/kicked from the internet.

What can i do to prevent this?

Here is the running config:

Result of the command: "sh run"

```
: Saved
:ASA Version 9.0(1)
!
hostname ciscoasa
enable password ------------- encrypted
passwd ------------ encrypted
names
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 255.255.255.248 
!
ftp mode passive
object network obj_any
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging asdm informational
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
!
object network obj_any
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
http server enable
http 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart warmstart
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto ca trustpool policy
telnet timeout 5
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0
dhcpd dns xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
dhcpd auto_config outside
!
dhcpd address 192.168.1.5-192.168.1.30 inside
dhcpd enable inside
!
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics host
threat-detection statistics port
threat-detection statistics protocol
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
no call-home reporting anonymous
Cryptochecksum:dac8da9f3df0438bed0b9b1b714a1e67
: end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

under the policy-map "global policy" enable http inspection also. HTTP in basic operation, i dont think require any inspection via Firewalls, though, in my personal experience I have seen this and thought that might be the case for you even.

Try to make that enable and let me know the results.